# Align button with inputs LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, button, inputfield

Hello everybody I am trying to align the next button with the inputs fields but I am not being able to do it. I have tried everything I can imaging but I cannot solve this issue. Could anybody help me?

[image]

My html code is the next one:

```
<lightning-accordion-section name="Documentos" label="Documentos">
            <template iterator:it={iterator}>
                <div key={it.value.autoNumber} class="slds-grid d-flex  slds-box ">
                    <div class="lightningCardClass slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-around_small">
                        <lightning-combobox label="Tipo documento" data-index={it.index} value={it.value.qx_TipoDocAportado} placeholder="Seleccione valor" options={picklistTipoDocumento} required  onchange={handleTipoDocumento}></lightning-combobox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lightningCardClass slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-around_small">
                        <lightning-input type="text"  label="Direccion URL" data-index={it.index} value={it.value.qx_DireccionUrl} max-length="255" required  onchange={handleDireccionURL}></lightning-input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lightningCardClass slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-around_small" >
                        <template if:false={it.value.recordId}>
                            <lightning-button onclick={onRemove} if:false={it.first} variant="destructive"  label='Borrar'
                                data-index={it.index}  class="slds-var-m-left_x-small">
                            </lightning-button>
                        </template>
                        <lightning-button  if:true={it.value.recordId} onclick={onRemove} variant="destructive lightningButton" label='Borrar' 
                            data-index={it.index} class="slds-var-m-left_x-small">
                        </lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button  onclick={onAdd} if:true={it.last} data-index={it.index} class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Nuevo" >
                        </lightning-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-accordion-section>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the slds grid and putting each element in its own column, you can then apply alignment.  See https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#Content-bottom

Answer (score 0):

Lightning-input tag consist of label tag and input tag. The weird alignment is coming because of label tag.
Instead of using label="Direccion URL" use placeholder and make variant as variant="label-hidden".

Comment: Hello this works great but the problem is that I want to show the label and also the require '*'. Is there other way? Thanks